# NavigationController issue, About the navigationBar POP Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

There are two `ViewControllers` A and B (pushed B on A) and a `TextField` in B.

iOS 7:

Touch textField, keyboard appear.Then i pop B, but the navigationBar was not change, the title is still B's. And if i don't let the keyboard to appear, the issue is not appearing.

And there is no issue like i mentioned while i'm running in iOS 8.
I can't figure it out. Someone please help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be a problem. I've done something similar but I don't see any problem.

Try configuring the navigation bar appearance in you viewWillAppear method. For both ViewController A & B.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Do the setting here.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks, but maybe not about `title`.I mean, everything in `NavigationBar` were not change, `NavigationItems` and `Title`. They should be A's.

Comment: Owww.. Now I can understand what your problem is. Wait

Comment: it's not work for me. But i test this again, if keyboard not dismissed, then i popped B, issue appear.And these steps again, Xcode told me, _2014-11-25 14:38:47.128 nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2014-11-25 14:38:47.500Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted._. If keyboard dismissed, everything is OK.